# Get the data from a post URL C#

Tags: c#, html, json, post

I have the post URL which can return the data as JSON format when I parse the url with fiddler

How can I get the ID in JSON Data in C#

Thank you, I tried to use some functions in WebClient, but i got no result.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var body = HttpContext.Current.Items["RequestBody"].ToString();
```

**UPDATE**

Try this

```
            var url =
            "https://secure.reservation-booking-system.com/beapi/rest/rsearch/hotelinfo?hotelId=18234&format=json&lang=fr-fr&domain=www.l-hotel.com";

        using (var webclient = new WebClient()){

            //Add data to body
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values.Add("hotelId", "18234");
            values.Add("format", "json");
            values.Add("lang", "fr-fr");
            values.Add("domain", "www.l-hotel.com");

            //Make request
            var response = webclient.UploadValues(url, values);

           //read Response
            var responseBody = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you , but where can I put the URL above ? to get the request body as your code ? so what I need is to fetch the data from URL first ? @bsayegh

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to make a post in C# with content in the body? If so, you can use WebClient if you want. WebClient.UploadData will send a post to whatever url you provide, and you can also provide a body. The body will need to be in the form of a byte array. You can get the body by doing Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bodyString)

Comment: Actually, as I used Fiddler to parse the content of the web page from that URL, I can see all the data as JSON or data in Webview, however, when I use the WebClient to fetch the data from the URL, I cannot find the same data as I did in Fiddler @bsayegh Thanks

Comment: So you want to hit that URL and be able to receive the json in the body? Try using HttpWebRequest like this -- var body = new StreamReader(HttpWebRequest.Create(url).GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: It return the error of 405 as I cannot get access to the content, but with Fiddler I could, do you have any idea about this ? Thanks @bsayegh

Comment: You need to set your method to POST. I got an error hitting the service, but ill append my answer with how you should make the request

Comment: I just updated my answer. It should get you the data you need.

Comment: Hi @bsayegh, I have changed to the following code notepad.cc/share/QliptgXlx9 this is the code which first get the cartID then use that cartID to retrieve the content of available rooms, however, sometimes I get the your session has expired but by keeping running again the console, sometimes I can get the content, and sometimes I get the Session expired, could you please have a look and suggest me the idea? thank you very much

Comment: I also have a question published here, thank you for having a check there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22806492/getting-the-values-by-request-and-response-with-parameters-in-c-sharp